# Forcing Wordpress Administration onto a separate SSL Host

Tags: wp-admin, urls, ssl

I've inherited a half-dozen or so wordpress sites. In a perfect world I would just put every one of them behind SSL throughout but I don't quite have enough IP addresses to go around and SNI will cut off windows XP users which is a non-starter.

The next best thing would be to at least centralize the admin functions behind a SSL-only site. So, what I'd like to do is something like:

- front-end site is http://www.example.com
- back-end sites end up at https://ssl.example-secured.com/wordpress/$SITE

There is a plugin which would let you force https for admin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) but it seems to require you stay in the same URL depth which won't work as I want to do this for a half-dozen or more wordpress sites and they can't all be at https://ssl.example.com/wp-admin

Any ideas how to make this happen?

I'll add we are moderately comfortable with hacking things in PHP, including the wordpress core, if need be. And we've got kooky CI / versioning schemes going on that make said hacks less painful.

While I understand the general "wp-way" would be to use multi-site here we really don't want to go down that path. Is there a way to do this that does not involve multi-site?

Comment: Is this multisite?

Comment: @s_ha_dum -- nope, too many different concerns involved to make that work.

Comment: How about using a multi-domain SSL certificate (UCC)?

Comment: @MatthewBoynes : that would require enough IPs to cover all sites or using SNI which cuts of clients so I that approach won't exactly work.

Comment: Multi-domain certificates require one IP, do not require SNI, and work great across old clients (specifically, there are no issues with XP). I've used these extensively without issue. [Further reading at Godaddy](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3908/what-is-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate).

Comment: Except you have to reissue them when you add a site which is something we don't wish to take on.

Comment: 'Tis the path of least resistance, trust me. Use the UCC for your inherited sites. Put new sites on a multi-site install (and for that, buy a wildcard cert). Now you don't have to ever re-issue the cert because you aren't adding any sites to it. 20 minutes worth of work and you're done. Furthermore, you're not hacking something together that _will_ have issues, and you have no anxiety about future updates, waiting for one of them to topple the house of cards.

Comment: Thanks -- I do get where you are coming from but that solution isn't workable. We don't want to be on multi-site as this is too multi-headed for that to work and our sites are not under *.example.com so a wildcard cert doesn't work. Furthermore, you can't have multiple virtual sites running on a single IP using a UCC cert (or any other combination of certs) without SNI so the structure doesn't you suggested isn't quite feasable anyhow. Finally, we have had to monkeypatch wordpress core a few times and we've got a system in place to handle that and keep current so hacking things is not a prob.

Comment: I have a lot of experience in this area and I assure you that everything I said is accurate, proven, and running for many live sites as we speak without issue. With regards to the wildcard cert, multisite with the [domain mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) allows sites to have their own domain, while keeping the WordPress admin on another domain (as a subdomain). I only point this out for others who come along with similar questions in the future, it's no skin off my back if you don't heed my advice :-). Best of luck!

Comment: @WyattBarnett : Let'

Comment: I agree with @MatthewBoynes here. Multi-site is the way to go. We have a multi-site setup with ONE SSL cert that works for admin across multiple domain names with domain mapping in place (same plugin as above). Of course once logging in, the URL is noticabley different, but that is hardly a concern to the client.

Comment: @NathanPowell -- I get where you and Matthew are coming from here but multi-site won't work in this scenario for a few reasons I've enumerated and a few reasons I can't get into. I've updated the question to reflect this.